# GA Conversions link transaction to client id theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics

I run an affiliate business and I obtain all my transactions from webgains/awin api. I have the `GA client id` which looks like this for example: `1735654072.1483261999`. Now I want to link this transaction to Google Analytics to see where my users/transactions are coming from. I'm using the following package for this

https://github.com/theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol#order-tracking-with-simple-e-commerce

The problem is that the transactions are not linked to the users. What am I doing wrong? Is the `client id` the correct way to link a transaction and a user?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up `userId` instead of `clientId`, `clientId` is meant for unique user tracking and not for cross browser and device tracking. `UserId` is the one you are looking for.

**Why not to use `clientId` for transaction?**
`clientId` is based on cookies, if user deletes the cookies, Google Analytics assigns the user a new one, connecting this to transaction will lead you to inaccurate results in user-based tracking.

You can go through the [official implementation guide for `userId` to know more about it](https://support.google.com/analytics/topic/6009743?hl=en&ref_topic=1007027). *Note of caution - You will have to send userId to userId enabled view*